# Account Resurrection as a function of Days Dead and Time to Resurrect

Tags: regression, estimation, binary, data-analysis, logistic-regression

I am a data scientist working for a company that takes user deposits. I wanted to answer the question of how likely an account that's dropped to $0 on deposit - or *dies*, in other words - would refund in the next 30 days - or *resurrect*, in other words. I decided to look at the number of days "dead" as my independent variable and I thus collected data every month again with the following independent and dependent variables.

- Independent variable (d) - how many days has the account been dead.
- Dependent variable (R) - did the account resurrect over the next 30 days? {1: yes, 0:no}

I used logistic regression to obtain a function of the form f(d) = p(R=1|d) = 1/(1+e^-(b1+b2*d)) where d is the number of days dead and f(d) = p(R=1|d) is the probability of resurrection over the next thirty days given those d days dead.

This is useful but I'd like to redefine R as whether the account resurrected over a generalized *w days* {1:yes, 0:no} and then figure out f(d,w) = p(R=1|d,w) where p is the probability that account resurrects over the next *w days* given it's been dead for r days.

My question three-part:

1. What is the least biased way to estimate this function from the data?
2. What is a bias - variance efficient way to estimate this function from the data?
3. What is a computationally feasible way to estimate this function from the data?